# "sooner"/"earlier"--which is the right word to use here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Can you join **earlier** than 2 months?

> Can you join **sooner** than 2 months?

What's the difference between these two sentences? Are both grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Although people would know what you mean, neither word fits well. They are both awkward.

**In less than 2 months** is what you are trying to say, assuming that there is a two month waiting period of some kind. We don't usually use **earlier** or **sooner** for periods of time.

A much wordier way to ask might be: **before two months are up/have expired**.

Comment: But would you go so far as to say the sentences are grammatically incorrect?

Comment: No,  it's merely a poor choice of words. We don't usually use **earlier** or **sooner** for periods of time.

Comment: **Earlier than** and **sooner than** would both normally be used with a **date**.